# How to get first N parts of a path?

Tags: shell, path, sh, freebsd

Imagine a path like this:
`/a/b/c/d/e/...`

Where `...` could be any number of levels further deep, i.e., I don't know, ahead of time, whether there will be 2, 3, or 13 more level deep.

How can I, using a FreeBSD shell, e.g., `/bin/sh`, extract the first "N" parts of this path?  e.g., first 4 levels, so that I would get `/a/b/c/d`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cut`:

```
s='/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i/j/k'
echo "$s" | cut -d/ -f1-5
/a/b/c/d
```

Or if you are using `BASH` then you can use shell array:

```
IFS=/ arr=($s)
```

Then print desired elements from array:

```
IFS=/ echo "${arr[*]:0:5}"
/a/b/c/d
```

Comment: Works on macOS.  I actually need it on FreeBSD (/bin/sh).  Let me modify the question to add that.

Comment: `echo "$s" | cut -d/ -f1-5` should work on FreeBSD as well

Comment: Awesome, works like a charm.  Don't know why I couldn't think of flipping the pipe around!  If you could add that to your answer, it will be good for future reference.